# CrystalReportViewer exception on on export/print

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I have a .net page (v1.1) and have a crystal report object on that page. I am using crystal report 9 here.  The report uses date time parameters passed to .net page as query string. The The issue is that the report throws following exception for a particular date (16 June 2013). Please note that the error is displayed fine, but the exception is thrown when I print/export using the crystal report's default functionality.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]    CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer.Dispose() +76
>   System.Web.UI.Control.UnloadRecursive(Boolean dispose) +138
>   System.Web.UI.Control.UnloadRecursive(Boolean dispose) +74
>   System.Web.UI.Control.UnloadRecursive(Boolean dispose) +74
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestCleanup() +24
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +218
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +18
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication+IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +179    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +87

I added some logging to see if there is any issue in the data but for 16 June 2013, the code just throws error and doesn't even go to OnInit or Page_Load of the page which has crystal report. Just to add, the code is on the test system and it isn't possible to debug the code, so I had to add logging/try-catch to investigate.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does it work for dates such as 24 June 2013? Is there a problem with the date format to the query? You may see it by logging the final query to the database (do set up logs in the database).

Comment: @Kangkan: It does work for any other date. Date Format doesn't change and the issue is that the code doesn't go into the database when I get error; it doesn't even go to page's OnInit/Page_Load. A thing to add is that the report is displayed fine but throws this exception when I try to export or print using the crystal report's button.

Comment: Try adding `<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="20000" />` to your `<appSettings>` in the `web.config`. Basically you want to increase on the default which is 1000.